# Какой формат быстрее всего распарсится?

Tags: xml, json, java

Есть кучка данных. Нужно их обработать, переработать и сохранить. Время на переработку - не особо лимитируется.

Потом в какой-то момент их нужно максимально быстро считать и отдать.

В каком формате их хранить? Т.е. скорость создания файла не важна, а скорость считывания нужна на максимально быстром уровне

Размер тоже не важен

**UPD1** Пока склоняюсь к MessagePack и csv.

**Итого**: CSV

Comment: А разве бинарный распарсить быстро? Его же перед употреблением разбинарить надо? А это лишние время. Или я бред говорю?

Comment: Бред говорите, верно. Бинарный вообще не парзят. Его просто берут и просто читают. Это просто и быстро. На С, к примеру, просто создаем переменную (одиночную или массив, структуру) и прямо в нее читаем из файла, как там в java - с ходу не скажу. Для того же DBF для java наверняка есть библиотеки готовые. Проблема может быть только в том случае, чтобы обе программы - и та что пишет и та что читает - писали идентично. С текстовыми форматами - XML, JSON этот проще, ибо как-никак стандартизировано.

Comment: @danpetruk Все зависит от того, в каком виде вам нужно отдавать считанные данные. Вероятнее всего, вам все равно нужно будет их парсить.

Comment: Нужно отдать в человеческом виде. Но именно после 'максимально быстро считать и отдать'. И отдать разделённо

Comment: Бинарные не парзят. Их, возможно, преобразуют в человеко-удобный вид. Но это много проще и быстрее, чем парзить.

Comment: Возьмите бинарный формат DBF - очень быстрый, очень простой, отлаженный, распространенный.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

О боже, век XML и JSON. Все забыли о бинарных форматах?

Быстрее всего - бинарный с полями фиксированной длинны. Вариация на тему DBF, к примеру.

Из тех нужно парcить - простой это CSV, к примеру.

Answer (score 3):

UML - это не формат, а я зык модеоирвоания.

JSON компактнее, чем XML. Так что его чтение в общем случае будет выполняться быстрее (как и передача по сети).

Есть более компактная форма JSON - [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/).

Также рекомендую посмотреть в сторону бинарных форматов хранения и передачи данных, например [Google Protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) или [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/).

Comment: В Protobuf или Thrift предусмотрено хранение?

Comment: @Softa Что значит предусмотрено? Это же просто формат. Ничто не мешает использовать его для хранения данных.

Comment: Гм. Насколько я понял - это протоколы обмена данным. А не формат файлов. Это разные вещи: например, в протоколе может быть предусмотрено подтверждение и пр. и пр. - как это "просто использовать для хранения данных". Вот я и спрашиваю - там предусмотрено хранение файлов?

Comment: @Softa В первую очередь это форматы хранения данных. Да, они предоставляют абстракции для RPC вызовов, но реализации как правило идут отдельно. В Protobuf это точно так.

Если мы описываем формат сообщения и можем преобразовать его в массив байтов, то ничто не мешает нам сохранить его в файл.

Comment: Что вы имеете вииду под "я зык модеоирвоания" ?

Answer (score 0):

xml из-за тегов сам по себе очень большой, json меньше. Но если и клиент и сервер оба на java то может родное использовать? Опишите подробнее проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Можно посмотреть в сторону [Action Message Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format). Формат бинарный, компактный, есть масса библиотек для работы с ним.

Подробнее:

1. [AMF 3 Specification](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/amf/amf3_spec_121207.pdf)